# Worklight initialization for Android always clears WebView history

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I noticed cordovaInitCallback is called each time Worklight/Cordova is initialized in an Android app. In particular, it calls Cordova's "clearHistory" to wipe out the WebView history. This has been an issue when I try to make use of window.history in a multi-page app since the history is always reset during the initializtion from page to page.

Since the comment suggests that the purpose for this clearHistory call is to prevent going back to an old page in a direct update scenario, could the condition be strengthened over an Android environment check so that it is only called if a direct update has just taken place? One case, for example, I can think of is when connectOnStartup=false, then direct update would not occur.

wlclient.js:

```
 var cordovaInitCallback = function(returnedData) {
            onEnvInit(options);
            if (WL.Client.getEnvironment() == WL.Env.ANDROID) {
                if (returnedData !== null && returnedData !== "") {
                    WL.StaticAppProps.APP_VERSION = returnedData;
                }
                // In development mode, the application has a settings
                // widget in which the user may alter
                // the application's root url
                // and here the application reads this url, and replaces the
                // static prop
                // WL.StaticAppProps.WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL
                // __setWLServerAddress for iOS is called within
                // wlgap.ios.js's wlCheckReachability
                // function because it is an asynchronous call.

                // Only in Android we should clear the history of the
                // WebView, otherwise when user will
                // press the back button after upgrade he will return to the
                // html page before the upgrade
                if (**WL.Env.ANDROID == getEnv()**) {
                    cordova.exec(null, null, 'Utils', 'clearHistory', []);
                }
            }
```

I am currently using Worklight 5.0.5, and have checked this same condition exists in 5.0.5.1.

Thanks!

Comment: Worklight was developed with single page applications in mind, you should consider dynamically populating html tags in your main html file if there's too much markup on your main html page. You can override functions in JavaScript, for example: `console.log = function(){return 'hello'}`. Now console.log will just return 'hello' instead of the default behavior. An option (that I don't really recommend) is to override one of those functions or objects (WL.Env.ANDROID = 'hello'). Note that this is **not** an answer, just a side comment :).

Answer (score 1):

The architectural design of Worklight is SPA (Single Page Application).
`cordovaInitCallback` should be called only once in the life cycle of the application.
That said, you can, if you wish, override it.